# grails taggable plugin - removeTag failing

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Probably a shot in the dark but hopefully someone knows something:

Im using the latest grails Taggable plugin v1.1.0 with Grails 2.5

In my controller i have 2 actions:

```
 def addGroupTag(String tag, Long membershipId) {

    def groupMembership = GroupMembership.findById(membershipId)
    groupMembership.addTag(tag)

}

def removeGroupTag(String tag, Long membershipId) {

    def groupMembership = GroupMembership.findById(membershipId)
    groupMembership.removeTag(tag)

    }
}
```

I can send a tag and membershipId to addGroupTag and after a call to addTag the tag is added no problem. I send the same params after to removeGroupTag and nothing happens. removeTag is definately called, but nothing happens, no error msg, no removal from the tag or tag_link table, nada.

any pointers would be much appreciated

**EDIT**

so i had a look inside the plugin and i found the method, it goes like this:

```
 for(domainClass in application.domainClasses) {
        if(Taggable.class.isAssignableFrom(domainClass.clazz)) {
            domainClass.clazz.metaClass {

                ---- various others such as addTag ----

                removeTag { String name ->
                    if(delegate.id == null) throw new TagException("You need to save the domain instance before tagging it")

                    if (!Tag.preserveCase) {
                        name = name.toLowerCase()
                    }
                    def criteria = TagLink.createCriteria()
                    def instance = delegate
                    def link = criteria.get {
                        tag {
                            if (!Tag.preserveCase) {
                                eq 'name', name
                            } else {
                                ilike 'name', name
                            }
                        }
                        eq 'tagRef', instance.id
                        eq 'type', GrailsNameUtils.getPropertyName(instance.class)
                        cache true
                    }
                    link?.delete()
                    return delegate
                }
```

now, if i change `link?.delete()` to `link?.delete(flush:true)` then it deletes the entry in the TagLink table, which is odd but a step forward as it means as far as my groupMembership instance is concerned, the tag no longer exists. However, i don't really want to flush the session every time a tag is deleted, whats with that? Also i would have assumed that the actual tag instance would also be deleted if there was no link to it because as far as i can see they are just going to sit there forever..

Comment: Well, It was getting deleted earlier as well  but as session was not flushed , change was not appearing in database

Comment: i guess so but shouldn't the plugin have provided some such functionality, despite a page refresh a deleted tag is rendered